# The difference between "simd" construct and "for simd" construct in OpenMP 4.0

Tags: openmp, simd

The OpenMP 4.0 has introduced the SIMD construct to make use of the SIMD instructions of the cpu. According to the specification http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf, there are two constructs to use simd to vectorize a loop. One is **"#pragma omp simd"** and another is **"#pragma omp for simd"**. According to the specification, both are used to vectorized a for-loop. I also tested and didn't find their difference. Anyone know whether there is a difference between these two constructs?

Comment: Did you try `pragma omp parallel for simd`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`#pragma omp simd` (the SIMD construct) instructs the OpenMP compiler to vectorise the loop that follows without worksharing, that is without distributing the loop iterations among multiple threads (if any).

`#pragma omp for` (the loop construct) instructs the compiler to perform the following loop while distributing the work among the threads of the current team. Therefore, the loop construct is only useful when placed within the lexical or the dynamical scope of a parallel region, e.g.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
   ...
   #pragma omp for
   for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) { ... }
   ...
}
```

`#pragma omp for simd` (also called loop SIMD construct) combines the two constructs above, i.e. it both distributes the iteration space among the threads in the team and further vectorises the partial loop that each thread performs. If not used within the scope of a parallel region, the `for simd` construct is equivalent to the `simd` construct.

It is possible to combine the loop SIMD construct with the `parallel` construct:

```
#pragma omp parallel for simd
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) { ... }
```

This combined construct creates a parallel region, distributes the iterations of the loop among the threads, and vectorises the partial loops.

Note that sometimes vectorisation and multithreading are not orthogonal with respect to performance. For example, if the loop is memory-bound, then both vectorisation and multithreading alone could lead to exhaustion of the available memory bandwidth and combining them won't bring any further speedup.

Also, when comparing the speedup with `#pragma omp simd` and with `#pragma omp [parallel] for simd`, keep in mind that multithreading alone usually delivers better speedup than vectorisation for the same amount of "multiplicity", i.e. a four-way SIMD-ised loop might (and most likely would) execute slower than when the same loop is computed with scalar instructions but split among four threads.

Comment: I don't understand the point of `omp simd`. I mean many compilers already do a good job with auto-vectorization. What advantage does `omp simd` offer?

Comment: @Zboson, I guess, the idea is to replace the many vendor-specific vectorisation pragmas with a standardised one. That's also what OpenMP did initially.

Comment: With some compilers, e.g. gcc, the only normal effect of omp simd is to ignore possible dependencies which otherwise prevent vectorization.  In many situations, it has similar effect to a restrict qualifier, but goes beyond that.  With other compilers, e.g. icc, omp simd has an additional effect of setting more  aggressive  compile options local to the loop.  For example, supposing fp-model source is set, within the omp simd loop it will be as if -fp-model fast were set.  This affects simd vectorized reduction and implicit vector math library calls, for example.

Comment: One thing to note is that except for the `simdlen` clause, the compiler can freely choose the SIMD length used for the loop. That means that a compiler might also use SIMD length 1, that is, scalar code for the `simd` construct.